# zsh initial working directory

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I start a new `zsh` session it always seems to set its working directory to the last-known working directory of any other `zsh` session running on my system. Is there a way to configure `zsh` to just start at `$HOME`?

For example, sometimes I get into really slow directory shared over the network or something and I'd like to open a new shell and do something else, but I can't do anything else because my new session is too busy trying to set its working directory to that slow path on the network.

Comment: That's not the default behavior. What is in your `~/.zshrc`?

Comment: Are you running under `tmux` or `screen`?

Comment: `tmux`     need more chars for valid comment

Comment: Maybe it's `oh-my-zsh`... Let me do some experiments...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doh! Turns out it was the `last-working-dir` plugin from `oh-my-zsh`. Removing that from my `plugins` array "fixed" it.